# Using Selenium with Django, server isn't properly created

Tags: python, django, selenium, functional-testing

I recently reinstalled both Django and Selenium, and most things seem to be working correctly, but when I try to run my functional tests the webdriver apparently can't find the LiveServer address.

The code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
import unittest

class GeneralFunctionalTests(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_navigate_site(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)

        # some tests from here
```

The webdriver starts, but the home page fails to load (it loads correctly on the normal browser with `python manage.py runserver`) so all tests fail as no elements can be found. `self.live_server_url` equals `http://localhost:8081`, which looks right to me.

Any clue about what I am missing here?

Comment: What error message do you get when it fails?

Comment: The webdriver loads to [this](http://i.imgur.com/zP1HL29.png) (usual "server not found" page). Then the tests fail (for instance, `find_element_by_id` functions raise exceptions as they can't find such elements).

Answer (score 0):

Well, never mind that. Once again, it was the antivirus messing in places where it shouldn't be. If you are having the same problem and your antivirus is *Avast!*, try deactivating *Web Shield* in the *Active Protection Settings* tab.